# How to get all users in a telegram private channel using telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to get a list of users using telethon in a private telegram channel which I am the admin for, and print it to the console.  I have tried the same code with a channel that is not private, and I'm having the same issues.

What is the username reference I am suppose to use?  I dont understand if that is my telegram username, my channel name, my as if I was to talk in the channel, or what.  Could someone please assist?

```
  from telethon import TelegramClient

   from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
   from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetAdminLogRequest
   from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest

   from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsRecent
   from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel
   from telethon.tl.types import ChannelAdminLogEventsFilter
   from telethon.tl.types import InputUserSelf
   from telethon.tl.types import InputUser
   # These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
   # api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
   api_id = XXXX# Use your own values here. https://my.telegram.org
   api_hash = 'XXX'
   phone_number = 'XXXX'

   client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)

   client.session.report_errors = False
   client.connect()

   if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter the code: '))

channel = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('Jimtest')) # Your channel username --is this the username of my channel? how do I get the right value for this?   It isays username, but seems to reference the channel name?

user = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('@jim')) # what is this value? my username? my "name" in the chat?  the username that outputs when I type as admin in the chat?
admins = [InputUserSelf(), InputUser(user.users[0].id, user.users[0].access_hash)] # admins
admins = [] # No need admins for join and leave and invite filters

filter = None # All events
filter = ChannelAdminLogEventsFilter(True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True)
cont = 0
list = [0,100,200,300]
for num in list:
 result = client(GetParticipantsRequest(InputChannel(channel.chats[0].id, channel.chats[0].access_hash), filter, num, 100, 0))
 for _user in result.users:
  print(_user.id)
```

I'm getting the following errors that look to be problems with the channel or usernames?  What are these values suppose to be?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./maybework.py", line 33, in <module>
    user = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('Jimtest')) # Your channel admin 
username
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
   packages/telethon/telegram_bare_client.py", line 459, in __call__
    result = self._invoke(call_receive, *requests)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
   packages/telethon/telegram_bare_client.py", line 551, in _invoke
    raise next(x.rpc_error for x in requests if x.rpc_error)
telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.UsernameNotOccupiedError: The username is not in use by anyone else yet
```

Once I fixed that one, or atleast got no error returned, I received this error on the next.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./maybework.py", line 33, in <module>
     user = client(ResolveUsernameRequest('jimtest')) # Your channel admin 
 username
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/telethon/telegram_bare_client.py", line 459, in __call__
     result = self._invoke(call_receive, *requests)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
 packages/telethon/telegram_bare_client.py", line 551, in _invoke
      raise next(x.rpc_error for x in requests if x.rpc_error)
 telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.UsernameNotOccupiedError: The username is not in use by anyone else yet
```

Comment: which version do you use?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code in Telethon V 0.19

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import socks

from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest

api_id = XXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+98XXXXXXXX'

################################################
# invite link for private channel
inveite_link='telegram.me/joinchat/AAAAAE84o7DErer_YqAohQ'
################################################
proxy_ip = 'YY.YY.YY.YY'
proxy_username = 'proxy_username'
proxy_password = 'proxy_password'
proxy_port = 123456
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash,
                    proxy=(socks.HTTP, proxy_ip, int(proxy_port), 
None, proxy_username, proxy_password))

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))



channel = client.get_entity(inveite_link)

offset = 0
limit = 100

while True:
    participants = client(GetParticipantsRequest(
        channel, channel, offset, limit,hash=0))
    if not participants.users:
        break
    for _user in participants.users:
        print('user : ', _user.id, _user.username)
        # save User info to Database
    offset += len(participants.users)
```

- I used socks. If you do not want to use socks, then remove it
- Because private channels do not have a username, I used `invite link`
- You can also use the ‍‍`channel ID` instead of `invite link`. In this case, you should use `channel = client.get_entity(PeerChannel(channel_id))` instead of ‍‍`channel = client.get_entity(inveite_link)`

Comment: I am only can get 200 users with the above code, How can I get more than that? up to 30000 users